# Aligning all panel components java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, alignment

I am using the BoxLayout layout manager in java, and have aligned a bunch of components:

```
myLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
myTextBox.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
myButton.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
...
```

I have a lot of components, and this seems over the top. Is there a shorthand way?

I tried the following, but setAlignmentX isn't a method inside Component?

```
for (Component c : personPanel.getComponents()) {
    c.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setAlignmentX` is defined in [`JComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentX(float)).

You could cast after checking:

```
for (Component c : personPanel.getComponents()) {
    if(c instanceof JComponent) {
        ((JComponent)c).setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    }
}
```

If you have nested your components, it might be necessary to make a recursive method out of that.